# Sound Output from GarageBand (on iPad) using Bluetooth

Tags: ipad, garageband, speakers

Is it possible to use bluetooth to listen to the sounds of GarageBand on iPad? I don't succeed to do it. I hear the sound from the iPad's speaker. But I can do it when I listen to iTunes for instance.

Is this a preference to be set in GarageBand itself?

Comment: I don't have a Bluetooth speaker myself, but try AirPlay (from Control Center).

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, theres no bluetooth option in Garageband for iPad.